# how to toggle 3 or more font-awesome icons dynamically in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, font-awesome

i am creating a rock-paper-scissors mini game with vue and i try to find a way to toggle classes like variables. for example:

```html
<template>
  <div id="human">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="h2 mb-5">Human</div>

      <!-- PLEASE CHECK BELOW HERE -->
      <i class="play-hand far fa-hand-{{ iconName }}"></i>
      <!-- OR -->
      <i class="play-hand far {{ icon }}"></i>

      <div class="h3 mt-4">{{ activeHand }}</div>
      <div class="row select-hand mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <i class="far fa-hand-rock" @click="setHand(hands[0])"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <i class="far fa-hand-paper" @click="setHand(hands[1])"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <i class="far fa-hand-scissors" @click="setHand(hands[2])"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

i marked with a commentary. I am pretty sure you get what i want to do.
I don't want to use `document.querySelector()` for this.

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      activeHand: 'Choose a Hand',
      hands: [
        {
          name: 'Rock',
          strength: 'scissor',
          weakness: 'paper',
          icon: 'fa-hand-rock'
        },
        {
          name: 'Paper',
          strength: 'rock',
          weakness: 'scissor',
          icon: 'fa-hand-paper'
        },
        {
          name: 'Scissor',
          strength: 'paper',
          weakness: 'rock',
          icon: 'fa-hand-scissors'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setHand (hand) {
      console.log(hand.name)
      this.activeHand = hand.name
      console.log(hand.icon)

      let playHandSelector = document.querySelector('.play-hand')
      playHandSelector.classList.remove(this.activeHand.includes(hand))
      playHandSelector.classList.add(hand.icon)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#human .far {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>
```

There must be a vue way to toggle a class dynamically by name. maybe without a true/false toggeling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Vue's `v-bind` directive for class bindings and put any variable usage into that markup. Take a look at the documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad).

Eventually your code could look like this.

```
<i class="play-hand far" :class="icon"></i>
```

Keep in mind to use proper class binding syntax in either using [objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) or [arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax).

Comment: You're welcome. Just keep in mind that mustache style `{{ }}` only works within content areas of your markup. For any expression and variable binding you have to use `v-bind` or (as a shorthand) the `:` style.